# Do-While loop breaks despite not fulfilling conditions

Tags: javascript, random, do-while, boolean-logic

This is probably a simple fix but when I run the loop below r1 and r2 sometimes don't fulfill the conditions to break the loop but the loop still breaks and returns the values. For example the loop breaks even if `Math.abs(r1-r2)<3`

```
  let r1
  let r2
  do{
    r1 = Math.round(Math.random()*(elementsToSwap.length-1))
    r2 = Math.round(Math.random()*(elementsToSwap.length-1))
  }while(
    (Math.abs(r1-r2)<3)
    &&prev.includes(r1)
    &&prev.includes(r2)
  )
```

What am I doing wrong?

`elementsToSwap` and `prev` are both arrays.

Comment: You're using `&&` so the condition also depends on the other two expressions. Check the values of `prev.includes(r1)` and `prev.includes(r2)`

Comment: @AHMEDSAJJAD those are "AND" operators so the loop should only break if all 3 conditions return false right? My issue is that the loop breaks sometimes even when 1 of these conditions returns true.

Comment: its actually the other way around. In `AND` boolean expressions `A & B & C` will evaluate to false if even one is false. I think you want the `OR ||` operator

Comment: @TahaAttari `while (condition)` means to repeat only when the condition is true. And a condition with `&&` is only true when *all* the sub-conditions are true.

Comment: @AHMEDSAJJAD ah you're absolutely right, thanks! If you post that as an answer I'd be happy to mark it successfully answered

Comment: There are already hundreds of questions about getting `&&` and `||` confused. There's little gained by answering another one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use the `||` operator to break the loop when all three conditions are false.

```
let r1;
let r2;
do {
    r1 = Math.round(Math.random()*(elementsToSwap.length-1))
    r2 = Math.round(Math.random()*(elementsToSwap.length-1))
} while((Math.abs(r1-r2)<3) || prev.includes(r1) || prev.includes(r2))
```

**OR** `||` evaluates `A || B || C` as `false` when all three are `false`.

**AND** `&&` evaluates `A && B && C` as `false` when even one is `false`.